# how to count no of records in gridview while paging is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have a gridview and in this grid i allow paging with page size 10.
Now I want to find the total number of records on every page index.
For example on page index 1 I have 10 records and on page index 2 I have 4 record so how do I count the number of record I just mentioned above?

Comment: Usually, only the last page can have variable record count which may be lower than ur pagesize. The total count of records in the datasource + ur page size should help give that information as you will know your pagesize. Is it that the data source of your gridview retrieving only records for each page at a time and hence u are unable to do so?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still searches for a solution to this problem, here it is:

```
DataView dv = (DataView)YourDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
int numberOfRows = int.Parse(dv.Table.Compute("Count(datakey)", "").ToString());
```

This also works if your datasource has a filtering expression, you just pass filter expression to the Compute method instead of "", like this

```
string rowFilter = YourDataSource.FilteringExpression;
int numberOfRows = int.Parse(dv.Table.Compute("Count(datakey)", rowFilter).ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

If gv is your gridview with paging:

```
var currentCount = (gv.PageIndex - 1) * gv.PageSize + gv.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: so how i count records on current page

Comment: Edited my answer. gw.Rows.Count gives the item count for the current page.